# Return variable as void (*)(void)

Tags: c++

How to return an void (*)(void) variable from a function?
More precisely how to mark the return type?

```
???? getFunc(){
        void (*pt2Func)(void) = ...;
        return pt2Func;
}

void main(){
     void (*myFunc)(void) = getFunc();
     myFunc();
}
```

Comment: There are essentially two options: 1) use a type alias, or 2) try to figure it out, fail, use a tool that does it for you, realise it’s incomprehensible and then give up and use a type alias.

Comment: `auto` in C++14 :)

Comment: Just for the record: `void (*getFunc())()`. Obvious, right?

Answer (score 2):

The most readable approach is via a type alias:

```
using VoidFct = void (*)(void);

VoidFct getFunc(){
   return &f;
}
```

where the function to which a pointer is passed could be

```
#include <cstdio>

void f() {
   std::puts("laksjdf");
}
```

and the client could would be

```
VoidFct g = getFunc();

g();
```

Comment: Or, if one doesn't want to hide pointers with type aliases: `using VoidFct = void(); VoidFct* getFunc();`.

Comment: @eerorika That's a good point. Reminds me of the fact that I usually feel uncomfortable when reading `auto var = getPointer()` instead of `auto *var = getPointer()`.